# Extend method that works like JQuery.Extend

Tags: c#, nuget-package

Is there a nice Extend method in a nice thin **Nuget** package anywhere?

One that works like [jQuery.Extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

The reason I ask is that I have view models and database models that are pretty similar. I want a quick way to convert to and from.

Comment: are you looking for Extension Methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx ?

Comment: No not extensions methods, I think I might have just found the solution here http://automapper.org/

Comment: Ah yes, auto-mappers. that one i've used before, works as described on the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automapper does exactly what I wanted. I added the logic as view model extensions so I could do this:

```
var dbModel = myViewModel.ToMyDBModel();
```